# Работает ли связка с контроллером fxml установленным программно?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Создается экземпляр `FXMLLoader` с передачей в конструктор `fxml`-ресурса. В `fxml`-разметке присутствует элемент у которого указан метод *контроллера* для обработки *события*. *Контроллер* указывается программно через `fxmlLoader.setController(controller)`. В *рантайме* выдает ошибку том, что нет *контроллера*. Так и должно быть, или мне искать ошибку в коде?

Comment: укажите контроллер в `fxml` файле: `fx:controller`

Comment: Изначально так и было. Но `fxml` файл должен лежать в поддиректории класса. А возможно в будущем где-нибудь еще. Хотелось бы иметь некую гибкость в хранении ресурсов, а иначе придется менять пути не только ресурсов в java программах, но и пути контроллеров у `fxml`-разметок

Comment: `fxml` файлы должны лежать в папке `resources` вашего проекта. Вот как раз таки если ресурсы будут колесить по проекту и придется менять постоянно ссылки. А так для этого есть отдельно отведенная папка. Окромя как прописать контроллер в `fxml` файле вариантов нет.

Comment: @Tsyklop, вообще то есть:) Только что нашел ошибку, и все работает. А так спасибо за совет, а то я еще не очень понимаю, как правильно организовывать иерархию(учитывая особенность пакетов java). Думаю вопрос удалять, кому-то может пригодиться?

Comment: Как же? покажите всем

Answer (score 0):

Вот так я установил контроллер программно:

```
FXMLLoader pageLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Page.fxml"));
PageController pageController = new PageController();
pageLoader.setController(pageController);
Parent root = pageLoader.load();
stage.setScene(newScene(root));
```

---

P.S. ошибка была очень глупая, просто забыл установить контроллер. Выставил ответ, вдруг кому-то время сэкономит.

Comment: Обычно установка контроллера и ресурса таким способом используется когда создается свой унаследованный контрол. Таким же способом я полагаю у вас не указан контроллер в ресурсном файле и ИДЕ не сможет выдавать подсказки и пропущенных полях/методах/стилях в контроллера и наоборот.